# Is it okay to have only one significant variable as a result of a logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, statistical-significance, categorical-data, predictor

I am running a logistic regression where the dependent variable is the adaptation decision. With that I am considering 5 independent and continuous variables such as

- age
- income
- educational attainment (expressed in years)
- farm size
- farming experience,

and another 4 independent dummy variables, namely:

- tenurial status
- access to credit
- access to info
- access to extension services.

Comment: Why would it not be?

Comment: I mean, wouldn't it make my study invalid or unacceptable?

Comment: What makes you believe that it *might* make your study invalid or unacceptable?

Comment: i don't really know. I have another question. is it okay?

Comment: it is about productivity analysis, this time. I am going to compare the productivity of a farm that adopts a particular strategy with that of a farm that do not. My professor suggested that I can just compute for the yield of each farm and then compare. so, my question is this: Among my respondents, can I just randomly choose farms of the same characteristics to compare (i.e. 1 hectare farm size, owned by the farmer-respondent himself)?

Comment: Please post separate questions separately.

Comment: There's no question being asked in the question body, so I'm voting to close this as _"unclear what you're asking"_

Answer (score 1):

There is no arbitrary number of variables that "should" or need to be significant for a logistic regression model (or indeed any model) to be correct or valid. Significance is a function of your data, and if there are no associations in your data, that is your result.

My Masters degree involved a model with no significant variables at the end of the day.

Comment: Anyway, please notice that assessing that only one variable is significant needs more that running a logistic regression analysis and looking at p-values.

Comment: Apologies for off-topic ping: there is a suggestion on Meta to make [randomized-experiment] a synonym of [random-allocation] tag (http://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4651). You have enough reputation in this tag in order to vote for this suggestion here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/random-allocation/synonyms - it now needs 4 upvotes to go through. If you disagree with the proposal, consider commenting on Meta to explain why. I will delete this comment soon. Cheers.